# concat 2 observable, and get booth their value in the same time

Tags: rxjs

Let's say I have the following : https://stackblitz.com/edit/concat

```
import {concat} from "rxjs/observable/concat";
import {fullObserver, stream} from "./utils";

const a = stream('a', 200, 3, 'partial');
const b = stream('b', 200, 3, 'partial');
concat(a, b).subscribe(fullObserver('concat'));
```

This will, subscribe to a, give me the result of a, then subscribe to b, and get the b result.

but, how do I do the follow,

```
subscribe to a => a complete
subscribe to b => b complete
get the result of a and b in an array like when booth are completed
```

its like a forkJoin but with a concat, so that all subscription are sequential. How could I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [`toArray()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/toArray) operator that will collect all `next` notifications and re-emit them in a single array after its source completes (`concat` will complete after all its source complete).

So in your case it will look like this:

```
concat(a, b).pipe(toArray()).subscribe(fullObserver('concat'));
```

Btw, you don't need to be importing "creation operators" such as `concat` or `timer` from `rxjs/observable/*` and you import them from just `rxjs`.

Comment: I found that out, and forgot to answer myself. Thank you